# Docker: adding a file from a parent directory

Tags: docker

In my `Dockerfile` I've got :

```
ADD ../../myapp.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/
```

That file exists as `ls ../../myapp.war` returns me the correct file but when I execute `sudo docker build -t myapp .` I've got :

```
Step 1 : ADD ../../myapp.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/
2014/07/02 19:18:09 ../../myapp.war: no such file or directory
```

Does somebody know why and how to do it correctly?

Comment: Some workarounds http://superuser.com/questions/842642

Comment: looks like a softlink won't work either: https://superuser.com/questions/842642/how-to-make-a-symlinked-folder-appear-as-a-normal-folder   or maybe works with some workarounds mentioned here

Answer (score 599, accepted):

1. `cd` to your parent directory instead
2. build the image from the parent directory, specifying the path to your Dockerfile

```bash
docker build -t <some tag> -f <dir/dir/Dockerfile> .
```

In this case, the context of the docker will be switched to the parent directory and accessible for ADD and COPY

Comment: Thank you! This works fine on a local box, but Docker Hub fails to build the image since it tries to do it from its same directory (tbh, just what one would normally expect). Is there any way to do the same trick in Docker Hub?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could push the image to the registry instead of using automated build.

Comment: `-f` *doesn't* appear to be deprecated per the docs -> _Specify a Dockerfile (-f)_: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f

Comment: As I read this bulletin, the '-f' flag has only been deprecated on the 'tag' command -
https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#separator--of---security-opt-flag-on-docker-run

Comment: I just ran into something that I thought I might be worth adding. While trying to copy a file from inside a folder named `bin` this error still came up for this command, moving it to folder with a different name allowed it to complete. No idea why.

Comment: Won't *any* changes to files in the parent dir bump the docker versions and force a rebuild though?

Comment: you can also do relative path to up folder with ../.. so now you are one level above =)   just make sure in your Dockerfile in the copy section that you also start from the same level, that way you can incorporate folder that are outside where the Dockerfile lives

Comment: but why doesn't `COPY ../../.. .` work for me - I keep seing the contents of the current directory where I ran docker build?

Comment: @Boedy can you give a concrete example? I tried `docker build -t my_img -f /Users/miranda9/repo .` and I still can't get it to work with error: `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open /Users/miranda9/.Trash: operation not permitted`. Not sure why its trying to do that...? what is going on?

Comment: If anybody comes across the same issue as me, you want to then specify 
ADD myapp.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ 
rather than 
ADD ../../myapp.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/
in the docker file.

Answer (score 271):

With docker-compose, you could set context folder:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'    
services:
  yourservice:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/yourservice/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Be careful where you set your context to because large files/folders will make the process hang. You'll want to ignore them with .dockerignore and more appropriately set your context to the point where you really need it.

Comment: Using docker-compose as a shortcut to solve this problem of context build is not bad at the moment anyway.

Comment: Should dockerfile path be relative to the new context or to docker compose file?

Comment: "When the value supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file. " https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Answer (score 185):

Unfortunately, (for practical and security reasons I guess), if you want to add/copy local content, it must be located at the same level in the directory tree as the `Dockerfile`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you
> **cannot ADD ../something**/something, because the first step of a docker
> build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the
> docker daemon.

**EDIT:** There's now an option (`-f`) to set the path of your Dockerfile ; it can be used to achieve what you want, see @Boedy 's response.

Comment: Is there a "clean" workaround for this? I'd rather not restructure my whole project directory just to accommodate this.

Comment: As said by @Günter, there is a workaround here http://superuser.com/a/842690/136024 ... is it really "clean"? Well at least it's a "workaround" :)

Comment: See better answer from @Boedy http://stackoverflow.com/a/34300129/2950621

Comment: is this why my `COPY` is failing? `COPY /Users/miranda9/ /miranda9`...yes it is: The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Comment: I'd like to hear any "security reason" for this, really

Comment: @flm, here is more information about increasing container isolation and, therefore, possible holes and breaches:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/hardened-desktop/enhanced-container-isolation/features-benefits/ - you might find answer here.

Comment: @Boedy response might work for a console execution, but does Docker provide something similar to run from ```docker-compose.yaml```? Upper in comments someone referred rising level up in file hierarchy ```../<folder>```, but this gives 'not found` error on the build and, actually, its stays aligned with ```COPY``` behaviour.

Comment: The documentation link is now https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Answer (score 42):

Adding some code snippets to support the accepted answer.

Directory structure :

```
setup/
 |__docker/DockerFile
 |__target/scripts/<myscripts.sh>
src/
 |__<my source files>
```

Docker file entry:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/dockerws/chatServerInstaller/scripts/
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/dockerws/chatServerInstaller/src/
WORKDIR /home/vagrant/dockerws/chatServerInstaller

#Copy all the required files from host's file system to the container file system.
COPY setup/target/scripts/install_x.sh scripts/
COPY setup/target/scripts/install_y.sh scripts/
COPY src/ src/
```

Command used to build the docker image

```
docker build -t test:latest -f setup/docker/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: great approach. Is it possible to share the code of `install_x.sh` as well?

Comment: I don't understand what `-f setup/docker/Dockerfile` flag is doing. What is it doing in your example?

Comment: also why does the docker command need the final dot if you are already specifying the path to the build context and Dockerfile?

Comment: also from where did you run that docker build command? what is the `pwd`?

Comment: @CharlieParker - `-f` option specifies the relative path of the `Dockerfile` wrt current working directory. The dot at the end specifies the current working directory. My answer already depicts how the current working directory looks like. Hope that clarifies it for you.

Answer (score 17):

Since `-f` caused another problem, I developed another solution.

- Create a base image in the parent folder
- Added the required files.
- Used this image as a base image for the project which in a descendant folder.

The `-f` flag does not solved my problem because my `onbuild` image looks for a file in a folder and had to call like this:

`-f foo/bar/Dockerfile foo/bar`

instead of

`-f foo/bar/Dockerfile .`

Also note that this is only solution for some cases as `-f` flag

Comment: Clever idea!  multi-stage build to carry over files you need!  Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: Do we need two Dockerfiles then? One in the parent directory and another in the current (child) directory?

Answer (score 11):

Given the following setup:

```
+ parent
    + service1
        - some_file.json
    + service2
        - Dockerfile
```

If you have a Dockerfile in `service2` and want to copy `some_file.json` from `service1`, you can run this *inside* the service2 directory:

`docker build -t my_image ../ --file Dockerfile`

This will set the target context one level above. The tricky part here is that the target Dockerfile is set explicitly (as it is not in the target context).

In `service2/Dockerfile`, you must issue the `COPY` command as if the file were one level above:

`COPY service1/some_file.json /target/location/some_file.json`

instead of

`COPY ../service1/some_file.json /target/location/some_file.json # will not work`

Answer (score 8):

If using docker-compose.yml, there is `additional_contexts` in the API that we can use to take resources from a parent folder outside the main context.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#additional_contexts

Here is how it works:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'    
services:
  my_service:
    build:
      context: ./
      additional_contexts:
         assets: ../../assets
      dockerfile: ./docker/my_service/Dockerfile
```

```
# Dockerfile
...
COPY --from:assets . /app/assets
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Let setting context: ../../ in parent folder in docker-compose.yml
Ex:

```
app:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./source/docker/dockerfile/Dockerfile
```

Comment: this is real answer to original question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have your directories tree like this:

```
dir0
├───dir1
│   └───dir11
|   |   └───dockerfile
|   └───dir12 (current)
└───dir2 (content to be copied)
```

and your dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM baseImage
COPY / /content
```

Let's say you want to copy **dir2** content into a new docker image using `COPY` or `ADD` of **dockerfile** that is in **dir11** and your **current directory** is **dir12**

You will have to run this command in order to build your image properly:

```sh
docker build -t image-name:tag -f ../dir11/dockerfile ../../dir2
```

- `-t your-image-name` Name and optionally a tag in the 'name:tag' format
- `-f ../dir11/dockerfile` Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
- `../../dir2` path to be current for COPY or ADD commands

## Update

Let's say you run this by mistake:

```sh
docker build -t image-name:tag -f ../dir11/dockerfile ../../
```

This will not solve your problem because in this case the `COPY / /content` will look like it's copying **dir0** content (dir1 & dir2) so in order to fix that you can either change the command using the right path or you can also change the COPY source path in the dockerfile like this:

```
COPY /dir2 /content
```

Answer (score 3):

In May 2022, [Docker announced it added the --build-context flag to the `docker build` command](https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/#:%7E:text=Conquering%20Complex%20Builds).

For your example, you can run your build command like this:

```
docker build --build-context myapp=../.. .
```

And your Dockerfile can reference that context with any commands that support the --from option

```
# Dockerfile
COPY --from=myapp myapp.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/
```

Comment: This feature is broken for `podman` on Windows: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/18840

Comment: If I am understanding the OP's question correctly - this is the best answer.   Using build-context you can "add a file from a parent directory" in your Dockerfile build.  Great feature - I was unaware of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using skaffold, use 'context:' to specify context location for each image dockerfile - context: ../../../

```
            apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta4
            kind: Config
            metadata:
                name: frontend
            build:
                artifacts:
                    - image: nginx-angular-ui
                      context: ../../../
                      sync:
                          # A local build will update dist and sync it to the container
                          manual:
                              - src: './dist/apps'
                                dest: '/usr/share/nginx/html'
                      docker:
                          dockerfile: ./tools/pipelines/dockerfile/nginx.dev.dockerfile
                    - image: webapi/image
                      context: ../../../../api/
                      docker:
                          dockerfile: ./dockerfile
            deploy:
                kubectl:
                    manifests:
                        - ./.k8s/*.yml
```

skaffold run -f ./skaffold.yaml

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this bcs the idea is for the build to be portable but if you must:

Instruct Docker to set `context:` to the parent folder. For example if you have a `Documents` parent folder with `/ssl` and `/my-proj` subfolders you could instruct Docker to copy ssl files to the container like this:

This Docker compose file would be at `Documents/my-proj/compose.yaml`.

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile_inline: |
        FROM nginx:latest
        WORKDIR /etc/nginx
        COPY /ssl/example.com/certificate.crt ssl/
        COPY /ssl/example.com/private.key ssl/
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: [80:80,443:443,59840:59840]
    volumes:
      - $NGINX_CONF_FILEPATH:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

- [build](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/min-wrapp/blob/main/Makefile#L22) the [img](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/min-wrapp/blob/main/src/docker/devops/Dockerfile) from an upper dir
- name the img
- enable proper volume sharing
- check the Makefile in the link above on how-to start the container ...

  ```
  docker build . -t proj-devops-img --no-cache --build-arg UID=$(shell id -u) --build-arg GID=$(shell id -g) -f src/docker/devops/Dockerfile
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for those who use composer is to use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) pointing to the parent folder:

```yaml
#docker-composer.yml

foo:
  build: foo
  volumes:
    - ./:/src/:ro
```

But I'm pretty sure the can be done playing with [volumes in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume).

Comment: It can't. _Note: The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent. For this reason, **you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile** because built images should be portable._ A host directory wouldn’t be available on all potential hosts. https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume