# How can I copy a directory or file to a docker image from localhost on ubuntu14.04?

Tags: docker

when i add a file or directory to docker image by a Dockerfile, I use ADD or COPY , but the file  path i want to add or copy must a relative path to the Dockerfile's directory. Is there a method for adding a file or directory from localhost to docker image by using absolute path? by the way, why the "docker cp" can only support copying file from docker image to localhost? on the contrary , it doesn't work ?

Comment: To quote the Docker documentation: The copy obeys the following rules:

The <src> path must be inside the context of the build;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: adding a file from a parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory)

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is that **it is not supported**.

From the [Docker docs](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add):

> The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD *../something /something,* because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Furthermore, symbolic links are not supported so it is not possible to *trick* the build by linking to a different location on the localhost.

However, *URL:s are supported* so one way to get around the problem is to to serve the files over HTTP if you enable a web server on your localhost (or in a docker container).

The command `docker cp` (unfortunately) is only supported from the container to the host, not vice versa. This is described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#cp). The way to go around this is to use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) where the data can be shared.

Comment: [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) can now copy files in either direction.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for those who use composer is to use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) pointing to the folder:

```
#docker-composer.yml

foo:
  build: foo
  volumes:
    - /local/path/:/path/:ro
```

But I'm pretty sure the can be done playing with [volumes in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume).

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround when you use `docker-compose`:

```
api1:
  build: .
  dockerfile: cluster/manifests/Dockerfile-NodeAPI
  ports:
    - 8080
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  command: "nodemon lib/app.js -e js,json,scss,css,html"
```

This still won't allow you to do relatives paths, however basepath in the `Dockerfile` will be `./` instead of `cluster/manifests/`

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file, simply use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

```
docker cp file.txt CONTAINER:/path/to/dest
```

To copy a directory, use a tar pipe:

```
tar -c "dir/" | docker run -i -a stdin CONTAINER tar -xC /path/to/dest
```

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on wassgren's answer, you can also you a docker [SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdks/) to do this. I'm not sure about every SDK, but at least [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) sends the context as an inputstream to docker. So, you specify `dockerClient.withBaseDirectory()` and `dockerClient.withDockerFile()`. You could use a more scripting approach and use gradle or groovy to do this and avoid having to "compile" java for this everytime.