# vs 2017 COPY failed: Docker File, CreateFile The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

> COPY failed: CreateFile \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder056926419\WebApplication1.sln: The system cannot find the file specified.

Sample file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1.sln ./
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj Web/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Web
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app


FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Comment: while building the docker from cmd i get these error. Project created from vs 2017.

Comment: FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80


FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1.sln ./
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj Web/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Web
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app


FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app


FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Stundio 2019 I found funny problem\situatuation. When you try to create dockerfile auto-generated by VS, generated **Dockerfile** placed in main project, *not in root(.sln) folder*, where exists **.dockerignore**.

I have next folder structure of my project:

```
<DIR>          .
<DIR>          ..
            82 .dockerignore
         6 305 .gitignore
<DIR>          MyProject.API
<DIR>          MyProject.API.Client
<DIR>          MyProject.Model
<DIR>          MyProject.Repository
<DIR>          MyProject.Repository.Settings
         6 567 MyProject.sln
         4 899 README.md
<DIR>          Tests.MyProject.Repository
<DIR>          Tests.Model
<DIR>          Tests.MongoContext.Infrastructure
<DIR>          Tests.MongoQuery
<DIR>          Tests.OdataFilters
```

Main project is MyProject.API.csproj (web api) in **MyProject.API**.

Auto-generated dockerfile from VS has next structure:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#VS generate copy command explicitly for dependencies of main project (model, repository, settings, etc.)
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Model/MyProject.Model.csproj", "MyProject.Model/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Repository/MyProject.Repository.csproj", "MyProject.Repository/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Repository.Settings/MyProject.Repository.Settings.csproj", "MyProject.Repository.Settings/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.API.dll"]
```

When I try build my image [according to insturction from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/), I have problem:

Linux container type:

```
Step 7/20 : COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder799586484/MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj: no such file or directory
```

Windows container type:

```
Step 7/20 : COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder753862033\MyProject.API\MyProject.API.csproj: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540011/7094638) I move my Dockerfile to the root folder (where exists .sln and .dockerignore files) and my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the directory structure.

1. Move your dockerfile to bin/Release/PublishOutput (after running VS publish > filesystem)
2. move all the files into a site folder
3. run `docker build`

https://forums.docker.com/t/copy-failed-trying-to-install-plain-asp-net-mvc-app-to-a-container/57217/3

I'm not sure how to get it to work automatically in VS yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this issue, especialy when you used visual studio, I am 98% sure that it is caused by missing exception in .dockerignore file.
You need to add your file/directory to exceptions in .dockerignore

Comment: yeaht thats correct... i deleted the dockerignore &   the copied worked

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being caused by the `.dockerignore` file next to your DockerFile, ignoring everything but `/obj/Docker/`:

```
*
!obj\Docker\publish\*
!obj\Docker\empty\
```

Update the `.dockerignore` to:

```
Dockerfile
[b|B]in
[O|o]bj
```

Answer (score 0):

For vs2017

docker build -t sampleapplication . -f sampleapplication/dockerfile

normal build fails because it is unable to find the exact path of the location of the docker file .so that you can observe the dockerfile.yml COPY command

["sampleapplication/sampleapplication.csproj","sampleapplication/"]

and we also have a simple trick those who use the vs .the docker file builds by changing the copy command in the docked file

["./sampleapplication.csproj","sampleapplication/"]

RUN dotnet restore "./sampleapplication.csproj"