# Dockerfile, how to COPY files from parent directory

Tags: docker

I have folder with files common for multiple docker images. How can I `COPY` these files to the image referencing the parent directory in Dockerfile? Obviously I don't want to duplicate this folder to all Docker projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: adding a file from a parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory)

Comment: execute `build` from parent directory, using the `--file` flag. then `COPY` will have visibility into the sibling folders. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300129/3029276.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `docker build` the latest parameter is called `PATH`. Here is a description of it taken from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified PATH [omissis]. The build process can refer to any of the files in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to reference a file in the context.

That means you have to specify a `PATH` that contains all of the files you need in your Dockerfile. Please be aware that changing the `PATH` to a different directory will require changing all of your `COPY` and `ADD` instructions to reflect the new directory structure.