# What is context: . in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn Docker and created my first Docker compose file. Basically, I am trying to create a Django web microservice and use docker compose file to manage it. Here is my code for my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

I don't understand the use of `context: .` Can someone please explain me this

Comment: [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) includes some examples of cases where you will need to specify a different `context:` directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is happening when using ../ with docker-compose volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049460/what-is-happening-when-using-with-docker-compose-volume)

Comment: Also, when providing no other attributes: you can provide the context to build directly:
`build: .`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**CONTEXT**

Either a path to a directory containing a `Dockerfile`, or a url to a git repository.

When the value supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file. This directory is also the build context that is sent to the Docker daemon.

Compose builds and tags it with a generated name, and uses that image thereafter.

```
build:
  context: ./dir
```

That mean, its a path to the directory that contains `Dockerfile` file. It purposes to build a new image for the service.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

In your case:

```
   context: .
```

`Dockerfile` file should be existing in the current directory (in the same folder of the `docker-compose.yml` file).

Comment: how can we use it in different environments?

Comment: How can we use `context` to point directly to a dockerfile that is named?

Comment: dockerfile: your_docker_file_name @DouglasGaskell

Comment: Does setting e.g. context: ./mysubfolder will automatically pick up .env file sitting inside the subfolder or do I still need to set it manually via separate decralation i.e. env_file: ./mysubfolder/.env?

Answer (score 11):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#:%7E:text=context%20defines%20either%20a%20path,location%20of%20the%20Compose%20file.) we know that:

> context defines either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a URL to a git repository.

In your case, `.` is a relative path representing the current directory where you run `docker-compose` command and where Compose can find a Dockerfile (and obviously also the `docker-compose.yaml` file).

The Dockerfile can also be elsewhere using the `dockerfile` keyword like that in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298876/3552975):

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  
  service-A
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-A/Dockerfile

  service-B
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-B/Dockerfile

  service-C
    build:
      context: ./all-service
      dockerfile: ./service-C/Dockerfile
```

The additional `context` keyword here is to tell the Dockerfile where to find its dependent files.

For instance, in one of your `Dockerfile` there are these lines:

```
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json
RUN npm install
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

These three files must be in the context directory or git repository: `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `requirements.txt`.

Comment: This answer is more detailed and explains the context well, as well as the dockerfile option.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be too clear, but if you're familiar with Python, this is similar to the concept of the "current working directory"
(in other words, the directory a python command was run).

Setting the `context` property allows the `docker-compose` command to find a Dockerfile AND any other files needed, for example with a file structure such as the one below. Think of the layout as `/root` containing multiple microservices (and the location you want to invoke `docker-compose`). If `context` is commented out, the Dockerfile is not found, neither is the `start.sh`script , without using absolute paths.

```
root
|- micro_service-1
|  |- compose
|    |- django
|      |- Dockerfile.dev
|      |- start.sh    
|  |-app    
|-docker-compose.yml
```

```
services:
[..]
  app:
    container_name: my_container
    build:
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile.dev
      context: micro_service-1 
    command: compose/django/start.sh
```

Replace Dockerfile.dev with Dockerfile( either works)