# How to run tests in Dockerfile using xunit

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, xunit.net

So I have an ASP.NET project in a folder (`src`) and a test project in a folder right next to the other folder (`tests`). What I am trying to achieve is to be able to run my tests and deploy the application using docker, however I am really stuck.

Right now there is a Dockerfile in the `src` folder, which builds the application and deploys it just fine. There is also a Dockerfile for the test project in the `tests` folder, which should just run my tests.

The `tests/Dockerfile` currently looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.103-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /tests
COPY ["tests.csproj", "Tests/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Tests/tests.csproj"
WORKDIR /tests/Tests
COPY . .
RUN dotnet test
```

But if i run docker build, the tests fail, I am guessing because the application's code to be tested is missing. 
I am getting a lot of:

```
The type or namespace name 'MyService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I do have a projectreference in my .csproj file so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your test code references some files (containing the type `MyService`) that have not been copied to the image. 
This happens because your `COPY . .` instruction is executed after the `WORKDIR /tests/Tests` instruction, therefore you are copying everything inside the `/tests/Tests` folder, and not the referenced code which, according to your description, resides in the `src` folder.

Your problem should be solved by performing `COPY . .` in your second line, right after the `FROM` instruction. That way, all the required files will be correctly copied to the image. If you proceed this way, you can simplify your `Dockerfile` to something like this (not tested):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.103-sdk AS build
COPY . .                       # Copy all files
WORKDIR /tests/Tests           # Go to tests directory
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test"]  # Run tests (this will perform a restore + build before launching the tests)
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem I am guessing because the Dockerfile is under the `/tests` folder. The `src` folder is next to the `tests` folder so the `COPY . .` command still won't copy the referenced code.

Comment: Yes, but you can solve this problem running the `docker run` command from the parent directory, and specifying your `Dockerfile` location with the `-f` option, as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300129/2651069