# problem with file structure while composing

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have this Flask-app and I want to Dockerize it. Here is the structure of my project:

```
- experimental-rest-api
-- games (project source code)
-- test
-- docker
---- df-api
------ Dockerfile
---- df-nginx
------ Dockerfile
---- df-postgres
------ Dockerfile
---- df-redis
------ Dockerfile
---- docker-compose.yml
-- requirements.txt
-- run.py
```

Here is the link to full project: https://github.com/tmpower/experimental-rest-api

I coded most part of the compose and dockerfiles but I run into some problems. The biggest problem is in `df-api/Dockerfile`. So could someone help me out with the problem. When I try to build that specific dockerfile it could not find requirements.txt.

How should I dockerize it in general. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have dockerfiles with only `FROM` instructions? Why not use this image directly? Secondly if this `requirements.txt` is used in `df-api` why not move this file into `df-api` directory?

Comment: Also look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory/34300129#34300129)

Comment: What's in that Dockerfile that doesn't work?  What _is_ the problem?  What commands are you running to build your images?