# How to copy the contents from the previous directory in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-build

Let's take an example of dotnet application code

- I have an application code present at

  `D:\eshop\DotneteShopOnWeb\src\Web\Application.sln`
- and I have multiple projects in the "Application.sln" like Web, API, Test
- every project is having its own Dockerfile like

  `D:\eshop\DotneteShopOnWeb\src\Web>Dockerfile`

The Dockerfile is as below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.sln .
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/src/Web
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/Web/out ./

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

I am executing the `docker build` command Dockerfile location.

I have also tried `docker build -t dotnetcore-eshop-mvc-manual -f src/Web/Dockerfile .` from `D:\eshop\DotneteShopOnWeb>`

I am getting errors in `RUN dotnet restore` as the sln file is not getting copied into the work directory.

Please let me know what modification I need in `COPY` to copy content from the previous directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: adding a file from a parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the working directory before restoring. I mean that your .sln files are in the path /app but your restoring is executed inside /app/src/Web location. you should do something like this to copy .sln files.

```
COPY *.sln .
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/src/Web
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/Web/out ./

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Comment: :- Thanks for the reply. The solution that you have suggested is not able to copy the content from the previous directory. what I want to do is like  `cd ../..` and whatever is there I want to copy them all.

Comment: There is no need to copy from previous directory. I guess your problem can be resolved in many ways! I changed my answer to another way but it’s not best practice

Comment: :- I tried your solution. It's still the same. I believe the .sln folder which is present in the previous directory has to be copied, else the `dotnet restore` will give an error saying `> [build 5/6] RUN dotnet restore:
#10 1.470 MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does 
not contain a project or solution file.`

Comment: If you have any Whatsapp or Google Hangout mail me your account at a.solhi@alibaba.ir. I will help you to resolve your problem.