# Issue in Copying DLL from Common gitrepo to the application repo to make application run

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dotnet application where my repo structure is as below

1. FolderA

   SubfolderA
   -Contains DLL file
2. FolderB

   SubfolderA
   -Contains application code and Dockerfile

   SubfolderB
   -Contains application code and Dockerfile

   SubfolderC
   -Contains application code and Dockerfile

When i build the Dockerfile in subfolder A, I want the Dockerfile to call or copy the DLL from the Folder A and run the application.
I have tried adding the following in the below Dockerfile

```
RUN ls -l /src
RUN cp '../../FolderA/subfolderA/OPCUAServer.dll' 'FolderB/subfolderA/'
```

The above command i added in the first phase of the image , but seems not working

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-focal AS build

# passing the root and nuget TLS certificates for the package to download 
COPY ./CIdependencies/rootca.cer /etc/ssl/certs/rootca.cer
COPY ./CIdependencies/nuget.cer /etc/ssl/certs/nuget.cer
WORKDIR /etc/ssl/certs
RUN openssl x509 -inform DER -in nuget.cer -out nuget.crt \
    && openssl x509 -inform PEM -in rootca.cer -out rootca.crt \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && echo $PWD
WORKDIR /src
EXPOSE 62501
COPY ["OPCUAServer.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./OPCUAServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "OPCUAServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build \
    && dotnet publish "OPCUAServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ARG DS_VERSION=0.0.0.0
# passing the root certificates for the package to download
COPY ./CIdependencies/zscaler-rootca.cer /etc/ssl/certs/rootca.cer
LABEL Name=OPCUAServer Version=$DS_VERSION git_commit=$GIT_COMMIT
#runtime-deps and runtime
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    ENV \
    # Configure web servers to bind to port 80 when present
    ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8079 \
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true

# Install .NET Core and ASPdotnet.3.1. focal
RUN dotnet_version=3.1.18 \
# passing the root certificates for the package to download 
    && curl -fsl --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/rootca.cer --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/$dotnet_version/dotnet-runtime-$dotnet_version-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && dotnet_sha512='6f06dbc4625fa8a0e64ffb9269b5f657e369fd28e7f27bfd05d4f422c6aa95847b5089d70760024bdf1100990dbbffce220a' \
    && echo "$dotnet_sha512  dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -ozxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet \
    && aspnetcore_version=3.1.18 \ 
    && curl -fsl --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/zscaler-rootca.cer --output aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$aspnetcore_version/aspnetcore-runtime-$aspnetcore_version-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='be29a7611941d9b20d5d3ece64d3ce3c2342ba24bf0382eed3625713ce89957fa15671403af16ccb588397fc0b27e7f028952213e08db6' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && tar -ozxf aspnetcore.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz 
    
# Create a user, group and providing permission to access the built files
WORKDIR /app
RUN groupadd -r opc && useradd --no-log-init -r -g opc opc
USER opc
COPY --from=build --chown=opc:opc /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OPCUAServer.dll"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: adding a file from a parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory)

Comment: No Max, I am not trying to copy the Dockerfile but i am trying to copy the DLL from another folder into the application folder. So on the DLL needs to be copied to multiple application service folders so that there will be multiple docker builds and application runs using that. That should happen through the Dockerfile