# How to access contents inside parent directory through dockerfile created in child directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Main Project

- Utils
- Auth
- MyProject

  - Dockerfile

For MyProject to run I need to build the contents in `Utils` and `Auth` folder, How can I access those while being inside dockerfile of `MyProject`. I dont want to create the dockerfile outside `MyProject`

Comment: When you build the Dockerfile, have it copy those items into the container

Comment: For that to happen I need my dockerfile to be inside the `Main Project` directory, how will I do that by being inside `MyProject` ?

Comment: Read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

Running the context from `Main Project`
Do the following
`docker build -f MyProject/Dockerfile .`. -f flag specifies the path to the dockerfile you want to build. Everything from root folder will be included in the context now