# How to COPY folder to Docker container in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, buildspec, docker-copy

I've a folder project structure as "cfn-APP" and inside this folder I've the following folders

NETPAYMENTS

- Config
- Tests
- Locators

Here Config, Tests, Locators are folders.

Similarly I've another folder inside "cfn-APP" (Again Config, Tests, Locators are folders)

PAYMENTS

- Config
- Tests
- Locators

Under NETPAYMENTS I've a Dockerfile similarly under PAYMENTS folder.

My buildspec.yaml is in the root "cfn-APP"

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN echo Copying NETPAYMENTS folder....
COPY NETPAYMENTS /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS
RUN echo Copying other py files from root....
COPY ../*py .
```

I want the entire NETPAYMENTS and PAYMENTS folder to be copied (along with the contents) to my WORKDIR.

But when the pipeline runs it gives error

#8 [ 5/29] COPY NETPAYMENTS /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS
#8 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::hybzvap3grz7r41j6b6le6xss: "/NETPAYMENTS": not found

I am sure the same error will happen when the Dockerfile is executed from PAYMENTS folder as well.

Any idea what's wrong with this?

Comment: Where are you running `docker build` from?  The container won't have access to directories above the one you're running the command in.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300129/361842 for more detail.

Comment: The build is running from AWS pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which directory (relative to the dockerfile) are you running that command in?

Comment: There are 2 folders NETPAYMENTS and PAYMENTS and each has its own Dockerfile in it. The buildspec.yaml file builds the image like this.
- docker image build -t 35xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-net-payment-api-repo ./NETPAYMENTS
(The ./NETPAYMENTS at the end of this command is the reference to the Dockerfile)
The NETPAYMENTS dir has other sub folders inside it (Config, Locators etc). I want the entire NETPAYMENTS folder copied over to the WORKDIR.

Answer (score 0):

Docker check NETPAYMENTS folder in current directory.
as you mentioned you docker file is present in NETPAYMENTS directory that's why it gives error

You can try following options to copy

1. `COPY /path/to/NETPAYMENTS /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS`
2. `COPY . /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS`
3. `COPY ../NETPAYMENTS /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS`

If your docker file is present in NETPAYMENTS app then using following docker file you can copy entire content and create new directory inside docker named NETPAYMENTS in workdir and copy same content
It not exact sol. but it copy all file in NETPAYMENTS  folder and create folder NETPAYMENTS and past all file

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN echo Copying NETPAYMENTS folder....
COPY . ./NETPAYMENTS
RUN echo Copying other py files from root....
COPY ../*py .
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried COPY ../NETPAYMENTS /usr/src/app/NETPAYMENTS but still getting "RROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::oekdy3l7ozrvpfo292hw017rf: "/NETPAYMENTS": not found". When I remove this COPY command, it works but only the folders inside "NETPAYMENTS" (namely Config, Tests, Locators) are copied but not the folder itself. What I want is to COPY the folder itself along with the sub folders underneath it.

Comment: I hope my update answer helps

Answer (score -1):

Make sure running the build commands from the right directory.